# Accessing NULL timestamp column with MySQL .NET Connector

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql, entity-framework

We are using MySQL .NET Connector 6.7.4 to access a MySQL database using Entity Framework 5.0 in .NET. After upgrading to version 6.7.4 we have started to run into problems with a timestamp column where NULL is allowed. We can save values without problems (i.e. the column gets updated properly in the db) but whenever we retrieve the entity corresponding to the row in the database the property corresponding to that column always returns null. We have tried to change the precision of the column in the edmx-file but that didn't change the behavior at all. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there any known workaround, besides downgrading to an older version of MySQL .NET Connector?

Comment: can you just try the query in the command line and let me know the if the result you get is the same ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by trying the query in the command line but if run the query using MySQL Workbench the timestamp is not null for that column.

Comment: What Entity Framework types is the column mapped onto in your edmx?

Comment: Nullable<System.DateTime>

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding 'convert zero datetime=true' to your connectionstring?
This will convert 0000-00-00 values to DateTime.MinValue.

see
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-connection-options.html
and
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-datetime.html

for more information

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use the IFNULL function? I.e.

```
SELECT IFNULL(mytimestamp,'0001-01-01 00:00:00') FROM mytable
```

This should return a column that is not nullable and always has a value. The returned value should either be the value of the mytimestamp column or '0001-01-01 00:00:00' (your default value).